# How do remove / hide the Bing map offline message when offline in winform C#

Tags: c#, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I'm developing a desktop app that uses the C# winform DevExpress XtraMap / Bing Map control.

The map tiles are being served up from a local source so the app doesn't not need a network connection to work. Unfortunately the map control insists on showing an

> The specified Bing Maps key is invalid. To create a developer
>   account, refer to http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers

message over the map when offline.

Does anyone know of a method to remove / hide this message?
[image: Message]